# Counting & Probability - Permutations

Tags: combinatorics

How many distinct words with letters chosen from B, M, T have exactly 12 distinct permutations given that the words can be of any length? For example, the word BMMT has 12 permutations. Two words are still distinct even if one is a permutation of the other. For example, BMMT is distinct from TMMB.

Comment: This is a somewhat unusual question. From where have you got it ? and what have you tried, and where are you stuck ? On this site, you are expected to give context and show some  effort, to elicit help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown work, I'll give you hints.

> The total number of permutations is $$\frac{(cnt_b + cnt_m + cnt_t)!}{cnt_b!cnt_m!cnt_t!}$$

> What can be the total number of characters? Can it be $3$, $5$, $7$, $15$?

> They can only be $4, 6, 12$. Can you see why?

> Go through each of them separately. Can you set bounds on $cnt_b, cnt_m, cnt_t$ and with trial and error reach the possible multi-sets?

> The possible multi-sets are $(2, 1, 1), (11, 1, 0)$

> From this, the total number of words is $12 \cdot 3 + 12 \cdot 3! = 108$

Comment: Please avoid answering contextless questions.

Comment: @Yooo I know that the post hasn't shown work, so I have only given hints.

Comment: Lol $\rm\sum Hint_i = Answer$

Comment: @Yooo XD Oh ok, I should probably delete some hints.

Comment: @Yooo Is $\sum \text{Hint} < \text{Answer}$ now? :)))

Comment: Yeah... xD it was not needed. :p

Comment: While I understand your hints, you might want to explain that $cnt_x$ means the number of times the letter $x$ appears in the permutation.

Comment: @MangoPizza I don’t really understand the 3rd hint, I know that 4 letter words are possible, but I’m not sure how a 6 letter word can bring 12 permutations. 6! equals 720. Therefore, $\frac{720}{x}=12$. So, $x=60$. But how do you get 60?

Comment: @Chantria I did not mean that all of $4, 6, 12$ produce valid multi-sets. I just meant to say that it is a possible candidate. In fact, you're right. There is no $6$-letter arrangement with exactly $12$ permutations.

Comment: @MangoPizza this is what I did as of now: So far, I have found that only a 4-letter arrangement is plausible. Furthermore, only 1 letter can repeat. There are 3 ways for the letter to repeat: Either the B, the M, or the T. Without regard to order, the arrangements are: BMMT, BBMT, and BMTT. Now, since they each have 12 permutations, $12\cdot3=36$. Did I miss anything here?

Comment: @Chantria Let's not forget: $(11, 1, 0)$. It also has $12$ arrangements. So, add to $36$, $3! \cdot 12 = 72$. Total = $108$

Comment: @MangoPizza ah, sorry, I forgot that. Thank you a lot for your help!! :))